# android app development - user created shortcuts with user defined names and icons change on app update

Tags: java, android, shortcut

Basically we have 2 launcher activities. MainActivity creates the shortcut with a custom icon and name chosen by the user, and we link SecondActivity to the shortcut.

Because the shortcut icon and name is selected by the user there is no 'real' default icon.

But whenever we load an update to the app in the PlayStore, the icons and names of the shortcuts created by the user are overridden by the default (the application icon and name).

By default an activity will inherit the icon and name from the application if it is not defined, but there is no way for us to define it since it is always created or selected by the user.

How can we avoid having the icon and name get overridden when the app is updated on the PlayStore?

***EXAMPLE FROM ANDROID MANIFEST***

```
<application
           android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name">
       <activity
               android:name=".MainActivity"
               android:label="@string/app_name">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity
               android:name=".SecondActivity"
               android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
               android:excludeFromRecents="true"
               android:launchMode="singleInstance">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
</application>
```

***EXAMPLE FROM MainActivity.java***

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
shortcutIntent.putExtra("Something", "Blah");

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);

// name is created by the user
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, aShortcut.getName()); //getName returns    a String

// icon is selected by the user
BitmapDrawable icon = (BitmapDrawable) aShortcut.getIcon(); // getIcon returns a   drawable
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON,icon.getBitmap());

addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
this.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```